# jquery slideshow loading issue

Tags: jquery, html

On my homepage i am using a jquery slideshow plugin/code. It is working well. The only issue is when you open the page, all the images are first piled one by one downwards before appearing properly.

You can see the problem right [HERE](http://www.pricepan.com)

Comment: Try putting the code of "slider" to the page header.

Answer (score 0):

Set your wrapper to hide overflow: CSS `#slider { overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 0):

instead of jQuery(window).load use jQuery(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue and tried overflow: hidden in our current project; it was a big improvement but still often showed one image below the rest before hiding it; in the end we resorted to wrapping the images in a div with css visibility: hidden and then set it to visible with jquery on documment ready, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#divSlider').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```